# Make div become scrollable if content grows beyond max-height

Tags: html, css

I've set my `article` element to a `max-height` of `90%`, but if content inside grows beyond this value it continues to flow through and below my `footer`.

Is there a way that i can make `#libraries` become scrollable if it becomes full with content? So content doesn't go beyond my `footer`.

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/oyrvbh23/1/

`html`

```
<div id="libraryView">
    <article id="libraries">Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>Test
        <br/>
    </article>
    <footer>
        <button id="libraryAdd">Add</button>
        <button id="libraryBack">Back</button>
    </footer>
</div>
```

`css`

```
html, body {
    height: 98%;
}
#libraries {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    max-height: 90%;
}
#libraryView {
    background-color: #A6A6A6;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm going to -1 because you could have easily put your question into Google and found the answer. Show some research effort here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [OVERFLOW](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property like this `overflow:auto` on your container:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 98%;
}
#libraries {
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  max-height: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#libraryView {
  background-color: #A6A6A6;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="libraryView">
  <article id="libraries">Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>
  </article>
  <footer>
    <button id="libraryAdd">Add</button>
    <button id="libraryBack">Back</button>
  </footer>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oyrvbh23/2/

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `overflow: auto;` to element with id `#libraries`:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 98%;
}
#libraries {
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  max-height: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#libraryView {
  background-color: #A6A6A6;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="libraryView">
  <article id="libraries">Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>
  </article>
  <footer>
    <button id="libraryAdd">Add</button>
    <button id="libraryBack">Back</button>
  </footer>
</div>
```